# Проблемы с сесиями

Tags: php

Написал  два файла. Один просто с двумя html ссылками через которые передаётся одна и та же переменная но с разными значениями. Во втором чистый **php**.

Вот файл **index.php** :

```
<?php
session_start();
$content=$_session['content'];
?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
...
...
<!--Ссылки-->
<li><a href="engin.php?do=pas">проль</a></li>
<li><a href="engin.php?do=reg">Регестрация</a></li>

<?echo $content?> 

...
...
</html>
```

Это файл **engin.php** :

```php
session_start();

$do =   $_GET['do'];

if ($do != '') {

    if ($do=='reg') {

$_session['content']=<<<here
.....  
.....

here;

    }

    if ($do == 'pas') {

        $_session['content']='...'

    }

} else {

$_session['content']=<<<he
...
...
he;

}

header("Location: index.php");

?>
```

Дело в том, что после переадресации, сессия не выводится, оказывается пустой.

Что делать подскажите?

Comment: user181105, Ваш код крайне низкого качество + множество грамматический ошибок.

Answer (score 1):

Насколько я вижу, переменная `$_session` написана в нижнем регистре, в то время как все суперглобальные массивы РНР пишутся в верхнем, `$_SESSION`.

Но вообще, не удивлюсь и тому, что не станет работать и после исправления. Уж больно какая-то хитровыдуманная сема, в которой сессии абсолютно лишние. Этот самый "engin" надо просто инклюдить в индекс. И получать свой контент безо всяких сессий и бессмысленных редиректов. К тому же индекс, который по одному и тому же адресу показывает кучу разных страниц, сведет с ума поисковики.

Скорее всего, эта разработка - следствие какой-либо из ложных фобий, коих много распространено среди пользователей пхп. Поэтому перед тем как писать код, надо сначала вербализовать свои опасения - по какой конкретно причине мы не хотим делать по-человечески, а хотим через спину автогеном - а потом пойти на СО и изложить эту причину и опасения. А здесь уже объяснят, что они беспочвенные и делать надо как все.